# (Wordpress) Irregular 3-4-3-4 Post structure

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align wordpress posts into the irregular structure like this:

---

Post 1 |  Post 2  | Post 3

Row 4 | Post 5 | Post 6 | Post 7

Post 8 | Post 9 | Post 10

Row 11 | Post 12 | Post 13 | Post 14

---

The posts are displayed as a list. I need some logic to align posts into the irregular structure.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Getting posts -->
<div class="kategorie-vypis">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="stredny-nadpis">Kategorie</h1>
    <ul>
            <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { ?>
                <h3><?php echo $category->category_description . ' '; ?></h3>
                <?php $catVal = $category->cat_ID; }
            $IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
            global $post;
            $myposts = get_posts('category=1&showposts=999'.$catVal);
            foreach ($myposts as $post) { ?>
                <li<?php if($IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID) { echo " class=\"current-post jeden-vypis\""; } ?>>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive logo-mini')); ?><span class="jeden-vypis-link"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></li>
            <?php }; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a couple of variables:

```
<?php 
$control = 3;
$current = 0;
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
  if ($current == 0)
    echo "<div>";
?>
  /***************************************/
  <?php 
  $current++;
  if ($current >= $control){
    echo "</div>";
    $current == 0;
    if($control == 3)
      $control = 4;
    else
      $control == 3;
  }
 }; ?>
```